# Baxter and Rennie: A question on Notation

Tags: stochastic-processes, sde, notation

On page 56 of Baxter and Rennie (Financial Calculus), we have

- The definition of a continuous stochastic process, in terms of the drift $\mu_s$ and volatality $\sigma_s$. Its important to keep in mind that the drift and volatality can be processes themselves.
- The uniquness result, a part of which tells us that for a given $\mu_s$
  , $\sigma_s$ and $X_0$, we can construct only a **single process** $X_t$.

However, the bottom part of the page introduces SDEs, which may have **multiple solutions**. The definition of an SDE is given in terms of drift and volatality which may depend upon the current value of the process - the notation being $\mu(X_t,t)$ and $\sigma(X_t,t)$.

I think $\mu(X_t,t)$ and $\sigma(X_t,t)$ are **special cases** of $\mu_s$ and $\sigma_s$, which would imply that an SDE **cannot have multiple solutions**. This is obviously wrong, and I would like to know why - hopefully in terms of how those two notations differ. Thank you in advance!

[image: Pg 56 of Baxter and Rennie]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\mu(X_t,t)$ and $\sigma(X_t,t)$ is indeed a special case of the more general notation $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$. The latter may be any stochastic processes (with the conditions given in the defintion). Note firstly that if $\sigma_t=0$, the SDE reduces to an ODE and we already know that not all ODEs are solvable (explicitly and uniquely).

However, as you said, $\mu_t$ and $\sigma_t$ (or $\mu(X_t)$ and $\sigma(t,X_t)$) do **not** uniquely define a stochastic process. You also need the initial value $X_0$. In the definition of the SDE on the bottom of the page, the authors do not include the initial condition $X_0$ which is crucial to have a unique solution.

- Look at two geometric Brownian motions with two different starting points, you will get two different processes with different distributions. Remember that for every $t\geq0$, $$ \ln(X_t) \sim N\left( \ln(X_0) + \left( \mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)t, \sigma^2t\right).$$

One can show: If you fix an initial value (and if $\mu$ and $\sigma$ satisfy some regulatory (Lipschitz) conditions), then there exists indeed a **unique** solution to the SDE.

- For instance, $$\mathrm{d}X_t =3X_t^{3/2}\mathrm{d}t$$
  with $X_0=0$. This is an ODE where $3x^{3/2}$ fails the Lipschitz condition, hence you can’t find a unique solution: for any $a>0$,
  \begin{align*}
  X_t = \begin{cases} 0 & t\leq a, \\
  (t-a)^3 & t>a
  \end{cases}
  \end{align*}
  is a solution to the ODE.